# Использовать ли phpdoc при разработке на php 7?

Tags: php, phpdoc

Раньше мы использовали phpdoc для указания типов аргументов и ответа функции. Теперь, с появлением в php поддержки типизации, некоторые задаются вопросом 
"Есть ли смысл продолжать использовать phpdoc для указания типов" ?

Без phpdoc:

```
# Возвращает год и животное
function animalYear (int $year, string $name) : string {

    return $year . ' год ' . $name;

}

echo animalYear(2016, 'Обезьяны');
```

С phpdoc:

```
/**
 * Возвращает год и животное
 * @param int $year
 * @param string $name
 * @return string
 */
function animalYear (int $year, string $name) : string {

    return $year . ' год ' . $name;

}

echo animalYear(2016, 'Обезьяны');
```

Comment: Есть неприятная фича.. если я правильно прочитал.. что даже если так объявите функции с ожидаемым типом, то все равно моно будет вставлять любые типы как аргумент, пока в файле не напишешь `declare(strict_types=1);` А самый прикол - Вы не можете просто кинуть объявление в фронт-контроллере или загрузчике. Придется писать именно в каждом файле. [источник](http://ahrameev.ru/article/migrating-to-php-7.html) . Так что стоит ли этими скалярами пользоваться с такими приколами))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский это да, есть такой момент, но у меня была надежда, что это избавит от килобайт phpdoc в коде =)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а почему не стоит-то?

Answer (score 2):

Все то, что может уловить автоматика, писать не нужно.
Все то, что она уловить не может - непосредственно смысл сложных методов и пояснения к возвращаемым значениям - в частности, может ли аргумент и/или возвращаемое значение быть null - писать по-прежнему нужно. Насколько понимаю, типизированных массивов все равно нет, и добрая половина доков сохранится.

Comment: Phpstorm пока что ругается если не прописать все типы, немного неприятно.

Comment: @АлексейАрх просто отключите ненужные inspections, либо по alt-enter прибейте их на месте